# AWS IAM Policy: The policy failed legacy parsing

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

while creatin a JSON IAM Policy in aws i get this error "the policy failed legacy parsing"

this is the code

```
    `{
       "Version": "2012–10–17",
       "Statement": [{
       "Sid": "LogCreatePut",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": [
       "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
       ],
       "Resource": "*"
     },
      {
        "Sid": "S3GetPutSend",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:PutObject",
          "ses:SendRawEmail"
        ],
       "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:s3:::<awss3bucketname>/*",
         "arn:aws:ses:<awsregion>:<awsccountid>:identity/*"
        ]
      }
     ]
    }`
```

i'm a new user of aws and i'm following this guide: https://medium.com/naukri-engineering/use-amazon-ses-to-receive-emails-in-s3-and-forward-incoming-email-to-any-external-email-id-84ffb394c70e
i hope someone could help me to solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: Those parts in brackets like `<awss3bucketname>`, `<awsregion>`, and `<awsccountid>` have to be replaced with actual values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete these steps in the guide:

- Replace <awss3bucketname> with the name of your S3 bucket
- Replace <awsaccountid> with your AWS Account ID